# Passing values from component data() to other files

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vue.js

P**roject type:** VueJS CLI v3.0  || 
**Question topic:** Passing data to other components/.vue files

I have a component which has a script whose data() looks like the following codeblock:

```
data: () => ({
  subscription: [ ... ]
  value: 10
  ...
})
```

I need to make sure that another component can read that data. Is that possible? Is it possible to pass the values of data in one component into another, and have it do this every time the value of that data is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways of passing data to another components:

1. From a parent to a child component: [passing props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)
2. Between 2 unrelated components: use a global state storage, like [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org)
3. From a child component to its parent: use [custom events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html). Note that in this case, you have to manually emit the custom events. For the 2 previous solution, the whenever the data is updated, other components will be also updated.

Comment: Vuex sounds exactly like what I need here. Is it really a good solution for me though since I will only need it for a few variables. Also, how difficult is it to implement Vuex in an existing project that is fairly large? 

Thanks for the help

Comment: @RohanKapur I'd say it's not difficult to update an existing code base to Vuex, but it might need some time to learn the Vuex patterns like state, action, and mutation. Once you understand them it's pretty straightforward.